# How to calculate the difference between two "elapsed" times with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns in Google Sheets, column 1 is a list of my times around a track in the format "01:23.456" or "minutes:seconds.milliseconds". Column 2 is a list of someone else's times around a track in the same format. I'm looking for a way to calculate the difference between my time and the other person's time to see how far behind I currently am.

I have already tried multiple different different date and time formats and even attempted to make a custom number format. I am kind of new to Google Sheets so I may have been going at this problem incorrectly.

For example, if my time around the track was "01:00.00" and the other person's time was "00:50.500" then the third column should display "00:09.500". Currently all of my attempts give me the same error which is "is a text and cannot be coerced to a number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TEXT(MINUS(LEFT(A1, 2)*60*1000+MID(A1, 4, 2)*1000+RIGHT(A1, 3),
            LEFT(B1, 2)*60*1000+MID(B1, 4, 2)*1000+RIGHT(B1, 3))*0.001, "00:00.000")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. It seems a little more complicated than it should be but I only need to use the equation once, after that I can just re-use it.